# Turtle graphics window's canvas color *not* showing up in Postscript (.ps) file

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, colors, turtle-graphics

So I have created a Turtle graphics program where the user can draw many different shapes on a canvas, and have implemented the ability for the user to save the canvas with his/her own name as a Postscript (.ps) file using a file browser. The file apparently has no problem opening up in Preview on my Macintosh. I have also allowed the user to import ANY .gif image they want and set that as the canvas color of the window or even just set it to a solid color if they don't want to use an image. However, I noticed that whenever I change **ONLY the canvas color of the window**, save it as a postscript file, and then open it, the **canvas color does NOT show up**, but the rest of the colors do, including the turtle's. What's even weirder is that if I instead set an **image** as the canvas, it **shows up** in the saved postscript file along with everything else. **So, why is this happening, and how would I fix it?** Any help is very much appreciated! :)

**P.S.** I have already seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537483/when-saving-python-turtle-graphics-to-a-eps-file-the-background-color-shows-on), but it apples to Python 2.x, while I have 3.5. I also don't like the solution of that question and I am hoping there is another, better way to fix this now.

Here is my save code:

```
def savefirst():
    cnv = getscreen().getcanvas() 
    global hel
    hel = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension = '.ps')
    fev = cnv.postscript(file = hel, colormode = 'color')
    try:
        if open(hel, 'r'):
            savefirst.save = True
    except:
        savefirst.save = False
```

And here is a screenshot of the canvas itself comparing it to a screenshot of the Postscript file-

Screenshot of canvas itself:
[image: Screenshot]

Screenshot of Postscript file (in Preview):
[image: Postscript file screenshot]

**EDIT:** I have looked around a lot, but I cannot find an answer that apples to Python 3.x.

Comment: turtle is a wrapper for tkinter which is a wrapper for tcl/tk, which does all the drawing on the screen.  Your question *is* a duplicate because the python version is irrelevant to what the tcl/tk save-to-postscript code does.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I was hoping there was a better solution than there was for that question, but I guess considering your response, there is not.

Comment: In my experiments with .ps output from tk on Windows, the problems were worse.  There may have been a version mismatch, but when I looked at the .ps file itself, it did not seem right.  When I seriously want to capture tkinter output, I will either use a screen capture program or look into the tcl/tk extension for creating modern .svg (scaled vector graphics) files.  (I have never used a tcl/tk extension, but I believe there are web pages explaining them.  There either are or could be SO Q and A's.)

Comment: @TerryJanReedy But what I don't get is why does a background **image** appear in the Postscript file, but not a background color?

Comment: R.Kap: I've modified my answer to the question @TerryJanReedy said was a duplicate so now it will work in both Python 2 and 3 — so your question ***is*** a duplicate now.